# How to show multiple dynamic rows using FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

A page which retrieves multiple rows from database and is working fine with simple php code. I want to display that page in print/pdf view(using fpdf).

I used FPDF library, but it shows only first row from database. I can't find out the way to solve it out.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['ssn']!="") {
  $search=$_SESSION['search'];
  $status='cash_out';
  include("connection.php");
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18);

    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction_info WHERE cus_id='$search'&&status='$status'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $branch = $row['branch'];
        $date = $row ['date'];
        $cus_pre_bal = $row['cus_pre_bal'];
        $total_bal = $row['cus_total_bal'];
        $trans_bal = $row['cus_trans_bal'];

     $pdf->AddPage();
     $pdf->Cell(0, 20, "Cash Out Report", 1, 1, 'C');
     $pdf->Cell(30, 13, " Date ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(30, 13, " Branch ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(42, 13, " Previous Balance ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(40, 13, " Transaction Bal. ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(48, 13, " Balance after Trans. ", 1, 1);

     $pdf->Cell(30, 13, "{$date} ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(30, 13, " {$branch} ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(42, 13, "      {$cus_pre_bal} ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(40, 13, "        {$trans_bal} ", 1, 0);
     $pdf->Cell(48, 13, "        {$total_bal} ", 1, 1);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Thanks Xorifelse for dropping me a line. Yeah, it's deprecated. But still it should be worked. And if use mysqli_query() or ideally PDO too, won't resolve the issue, right?
Acually I was trying to help someone who is already been coded like this.

Comment: Well, debug a little first. Does `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {print_r($row);}` give you the correct data? If so, you're using `FPDF` incorrectly. I'm suspecting `$pdf->AddPage()` returns a page you can write to, so `$page = $pdf->AddPage(); $page->Cell(....)`.

Comment: Yes, you got the point. I have already solve the problem yesterday. Thanks much by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue we have to use FPDF correctly as well as have to start looping after right line of fpdf.

**Resolve the issue this way:** I just started the looping after

`$pdf->Cell(0, 20, "Cash Out Report", 1, 1, 'C');`

Notice that we need that line to create static header row. So, just right after that line we need to start looping:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(0, 20, "Cash Out Report", 1, 1, 'C');
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction_info WHERE cus_id='$search'&&status='$status'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $branch = $row['branch'];
  $date = $row ['date'];
  $cus_pre_bal = $row['cus_pre_bal'];
  $total_bal = $row['cus_total_bal'];
  $trans_bal = $row['cus_trans_bal'];

  $pdf->Cell(30, 13, " Date ", 1, 0);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 13, " Branch ", 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Well, I've never used `FPDF` but I was close. Accept your answer.